# Unity Instantiated Object doesnt have Values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am trying to Instatiate Objects with the code attached but only the first Object has the Method awake called and doesent get any values out of orbitValues. The other Objects get instantiated but they also dont get any values. Can you help please?

```
if (listChecked == true & objectsCreated == false)
        {
            objectsCreated = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5 + 1; i++)
            {
                Ellipse orbitValues = new Ellipse(float.Parse(orbitList[i].attributes.inc), float.Parse(orbitList[i].attributes.sma), float.Parse(orbitList[i].attributes.ecc), float.Parse(orbitList[i].attributes.aPer));
                Debug.Log("i: " + i + " aPer: " + orbitValues.aPer);
                var tempOrbiter = Instantiate(orbit, Vector3.zero, transform.rotation);
                tempOrbiter.GetComponent<OrbitMotion>().orbitPath = orbitValues;
                tempOrbiter.GetComponent<OrbitMotion>().id = i;
                tempOrbiter.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, orbitValues.inc);
                tempOrbiter.transform.parent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("OrbiterGroup").transform;
            }
        }
```

The class Ellipse:

```
public class Ellipse
{
    public float inc;
    public float sma;
    public float ecc;
    public float aPer;

    public float c;
    public float e;
    public float xAxis;
    public float zAxis;

    float x;
    float z;

    public Ellipse(float inc, float sma, float ecc, float aPer)
    {
        this.inc = inc;
        this.sma = sma;
        this.ecc = ecc;
        this.aPer = aPer;
    } ...
```

and the script that should be with every instantiated object:

```
public class OrbitMotion : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform orbitingObject;
    public Ellipse orbitPath;
    public int id;

    [Range(0f,1f)]
    public float orbitProgress = 0f;
    public float orbitPeriod = 60f;
    public bool orbitActive = false;

    public float xOffset = 0;
    public float zOffset = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("id: " + id);
        Debug.Log(orbitPath.aPer);
        if (orbitingObject == null)
        {
            orbitActive = false;
            return;
        }

        orbitingObject = transform.GetChild(0).transform;
        transform.parent = GameObject.Find("OrbiterGroup").transform;

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, orbitPath.inc);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, orbitPath.aPer, 0);

        xOffset = (Mathf.Sin(orbitPath.aPer) * (orbitPath.sma - orbitPath.e));
        zOffset = (Mathf.Cos(orbitPath.aPer) * (orbitPath.sma - orbitPath.e));
        Debug.Log(orbitPath.e);
        Debug.Log(xOffset);
        
        transform.position = new Vector3(xOffset, 0, zOffset) / 1000;

        SetOrbitingObjectPosition();
        StartCoroutine(AnimateOrbit());

        gameObject.GetComponent<EllipseRenderer>().ellipse = orbitPath;
    }...
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the code to Start instead?   You could also have a function that accepts the orbit values as a param.  Remove the constructor from OrbitMotion, it serves no purpose since MonoBehaviours are created using `Instantiate` and not `new`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Exchanging Awake with Start actually worked but I dont get why. Removed the Constructor befor but didnt update the script here sorry ;D

Comment: Awake happens when the component instance is being loaded.  Think of awake as the faux constructor, only internal initialization should happen at this point in execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating them, then `Awake()` gets called, then you update the script values then, before the next `Update()` call, `Start()` is called.

`Awake()` is getting called on ALL of the instantiated objects, but it's getting called as soon as the prefab is instantiated, before you set any values. This means that the `id` for all of them is the same, and it's defaulting to 0, so it probably just looks like the first one is getting called (especially if you're collapsing the notifications in the console window).

Moving the work to `Start()` gets the functionality you want because `Start()` gets called later, before the first `Update()` call. `Awake()` is invoked immediately on construction/instantiation. You don't have time to update anything between instantiation and `Awake()` getting called.